# Need to learn information security

Tags: research

I want to learn about information security so I need some good sources to help me and learn that. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Information Security! Requests for sources are not on topic here, so your question will likely be closed. When you have more specific questions about security issues you are more than welcome to come back here and ask.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the exciting world of InfoSec! This field can take you almost anywhere and everywhere. So it's important to get a feel for what kind of InfoSec interests you.

**Some areas of study:**

- Risk Assessment and Analysis (Vulnerability Assessments, Governance Assessments, etc.)
- Offensive Security (Ethical Hacking / Penetration Testing) (Red Teaming)
- Defensive Security (Blue Teaming)
- Cryptography (Encryption)
- Malware Analysis (Reverse Engineering)
- tons of others....

**Getting started** *(find out what you're into)*

- Community College classes
- Reading Questions on this forum (to get a feel for what interests you)
- Download Metasploitable2 (a Virtual Machine you can launch on your computer and hack into for learning penetration testing, there are a ton of guides to walk you through exploiting it)
- IRC channels (for listening to infosec pros: #metasploit, #offsec, #kali, etc)
- Actually scratch #2, just READ EVERYTHING.. Knowledge is your best tool for making informed decisions.
- Follow InfoSec Guys on Twitter (start with @HDM and just see who he follows and spider from there)
- There are tons of resources but this should get you started.

Bottom line: there is a lot of ground to cover and it can take awhile to wrap your head around any one part of it. I'd start with exploring all areas and dig deeper into the ones that "speak" to you. Happy Hacking!